# How to get Windowid from PID from a electron Application

Tags: linux, window, x11, pid, xdotool

I want to get the WindowID from the PID of an Electron Process (for example riot-desktop)

I tried to get it with xdotools like this:

```
$ xdotool search --pid $(pgrep riot)
nothing is printed
$ pgrep riot
30461
$ xdotool search --pid 30461
nothing is printed again
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for the pid of the subprocess of electron. 
You can get the pid of the subprocess with:

```
PID=$(ps h -C electron | grep riot | cut -f1 -d"?")
```

now you can search for the pid

```
xdotool search --pid $PID
```

you can combine both commands to a single command

```
xdotool search --pid $(ps h -C electron | grep riot | grep witzerstorfer | cut -f1 -d"?")
```

if your ps returns multiple pid's you have to add more grep commands, for example if you work with profiles the command could look like this:

```
PID=$(ps h -C electron | grep riot | grep $PROFILENAME | cut -f1 -d"?")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find windowID of your electron application then you can use

[win.getMediaSourceId()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetmediasourceid)

Returns `String` - Window id in the format of DesktopCapturerSource's id. For example "window:1324:0".

More precisely the format is `window:id:other_id` where `id` is `HWND` on Windows, `CGWindowID` (`uint64_t`) on macOS and Window (unsigned long) on Linux. `other_id` is used to identify web contents (tabs) so within the same top level window.

Example:

```js
// In the main process.
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

// Load a remote URL
win.loadURL('https://github.com')

// Or load a local HTML file
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`)

// Print window id
console.log('window id is', win.getMediaSourceId())
```